# HTML5 input pattern validate letters and numbers

Tags: html, regex, validation

I need to validate password with these requirements:

At least 1 Letter,
At least 1 Number,
Min 6 chars and Max 12 chars,
Special characters not allowed.
Here's what I have so far.

```
<form>
Password: <input type="password" name="pw" pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,12}$" title="Must contain at least one number and one letter, and at least 6 to 12 characters (special characters not allowed)">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: *Special characters not allowed* - then why use `.`? Replace `.{6,12}` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12}` if you plan to only match ASCII letters and digits.

Comment: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033) may really benefit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is regex that solves your problem.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=\w*[0-9])\w{6,12}$
```

Full answer is:

```
<form>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pw" pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=\w*[0-9])\w{6,12}$" title="Must contain at least one number and one letter, and at least 6 to 12 characters (special characters not allowed)">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any way to allow one specific character like Space or . (Dot)? pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\s])(?=\w*[0-9])\w{6,12}$" 
*( "_" underscore is not allowed for me)

Comment: ^(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])(?=\w*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9 \.]{6,12}$